# Upload without upload button and browse button

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to use the Upload component to browse and upload a file i. What I want is only upload-functionality, but not the upload button and the browse button.I want to add a button to the page when a user click it the browse file window is opened so he can choose a file and upload it
I wrote this :

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);
    final Upload sample = new Upload(null, null);
    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    sample.setImmediate(true);
            sample.setButtonCaption(null);
            System.out.println(sample.isVisible());
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
            sample.setVisible(true);
            layout.addComponent(sample);
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(button);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You want a single-click upload. There is no need for an extra button.

```
// Make uploading start immediately when file is selected
upload.setImmediate(true);
upload.setButtonCaption("Select file");
```

Example [here](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#ImmediateUpload).

Comment: thank u @nexus but i really need the extra button i have to create by myself and lunch the browse window when the user click it

Comment: @AmiraGL why not using this solution? Or do I missunderstand something?

Comment: The upload.setButtonCaption("Select file"); already exists in the page, i will create a custom widget for this ;)